# Путь к phpstorm Linux Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, phpstorm

для ассоциации файлов filezilla надо указать путь к phpstorm. Для Visual Studio Code нашел , /usr/bin/code а какой для phpstorm, webstorm,.

Comment: Обычно продукты от jetbrains скачиваются архивом и устанавливаются туда, куда вы укажете. Можете попробовать выполнить whereis phpstorm.

Comment: Устанавливал через ToolBox

Comment: А whereis не находит? Может, в ToolBox эту информацию можно найти?

Comment: Отправь ярлык на рабочий стол, а потом посмотри внутри него.